# "Flatten" incremental updates in PDF

Tags: pdf, adobe, acrobat

I have an editable PDF which has been made with incremental updates, but I need to use the PDF with a code library that doesn't support this.

How can I "flatten" the incremental updates and just make it a regular PDF?

Comment: This question is unclear. You say you want to flatten a PDF with incremental updates using some anonymous PDF library that can't read such PDFs.

Comment: A PDF with *incremental updates* can very well still be a *regular PDF*. If a PDF library does not support incremental updates, I doubt that this is the only shortcoming of that library. Please first make sure you know all the deficits.

Comment: After playing around some more, I decided that the library was no good and ended up using pdftk.

Answer (score 2):

You can use Adobe Acrobat and save the file using the Save As menu option. This will merge all the incremental updates and you'll have a regular PDF.

Answer (score 2):

PDF is designed such that reading a PDF with incremental updates without knowing it has them is equivalent to reading the final revision.

If a library doesn't support incremental updates, it will likely load the final version of the file by default, so simply reading and writing the file ought to be fine.

For example, with the [Coherent PDF Command Line Tools](http://community.coherentpdf.com/) (free for non-commercial use) you can do

```
cpdf in.pdf -o out.pdf
```

and everything will be fine.

Answer (score 1):

I think many general-purpose PDF libraries should be able to do this while saving the document.

Below is the sample code for [Docotic.Pdf library](https://bitmiracle.com/pdf-library/).

```
string originalFile = "file-with-incremental-updates.pdf";
string compressedFile = "file-without-incremental-updates.pdf";
            
using (PdfDocument pdf = new PdfDocument(originalFile))
{
    pdf.SaveOptions.Compression = PdfCompression.Flate;
    pdf.SaveOptions.UseObjectStreams = false;
    pdf.SaveOptions.RemoveUnusedObjects = true;
    pdf.SaveOptions.OptimizeIndirectObjects = true;
    pdf.SaveOptions.WriteWithoutFormatting = true;

    pdf.Save(compressedFile);
}
```

As you can see, the library can be told to produce different outputs from the same input. You can, for example, remove unused objects and reduce size of the output file.

Disclaimer: I am one of the developers of the library.